# How to get my input validation and disabling/enabling my submit button depending on the state of the form in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I am using npm Validator and trying to validate the input info and then change the state of the submit address button depending on the validation. The way I have it set up now I can type and the text shows in the console but not in the UI. I'm not sure what I have wrong. The button will not change to 'enabled' either.

Here is the component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { CardElement, injectStripe } from 'react-stripe-elements';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { clearCart } from '../actions/clearCartAction';
import getTotal from '../helpers/getTotalHelper';
import { Container, Col, Form, FormGroup, Input, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import './StripeCheckoutForm.css';
import validator from 'validator';

const cardElement = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    width: '50%',
    lineHeight: '30px',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '18px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

const FIREBASE_FUNCTION = 'https://us-central1-velo-velo.cloudfunctions.net/charge/';

// Function used by all three methods to send the charge data to your Firebase function
async function charge(token, amount, currency) {
  const res = await fetch(FIREBASE_FUNCTION, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
          token,
          charge: {
              amount,
              currency,
          },
      }),
  });
  const data = await res.json();
  data.body = JSON.parse(data.body);
  return data;
}

class CheckoutForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    paymentComplete: false,
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    address: '',
    city: '',
    prefecture: '',
    zipCode: '',
    email: '',
    submitDisabled: true
  }

  inputChangeHandler = (event, name) => {
    console.log('inputChange', name, event.target.value)
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value
    }, console.log(this.state.submitDisabled), function(){ this.canSubmit() })
  }

  canSubmit = () => {
    console.log("canSubmit")
    const { firstName, lastName, address, city, prefecture,zipCode, email} = this.state
    if (validator.isAlpha(firstName) 
    && validator.isAlpha(lastName) 
    && address > 0
    && validator.isAlpha(city)
    && validator.isAlpha(prefecture)
    && zipCode > 0
    && validator.isEmail(email)) {
      this.setState({submitDisabled: false})
    } else {
      this.setState({submitDisabled: true})
    }
  }

  clearCartHandler = () => {
    console.log('clearCartHandler');
    this.props.onClearCart()
  }

  // User clicked submit
  async submit(ev) {
    console.log("clicked!")
    const {token} = await this.props.stripe.createToken({name: "Name"});
    const total = getTotal(this.props.cartItems);
    const amount = total; // TODO: replace with form data
    const currency = 'USD';
    const response = await charge(token, amount, currency);

    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      this.setState({paymentComplete: true});
      console.log('200!!',response);
      this.clearCartHandler();

    } else {
      alert("wrong credit information")
      console.error("error: ", response);
    }
  }

  render() {

    if (this.state.complete) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1 className="purchase-complete">Purchase Complete</h1>
          <Link to='/'>
            <button>Continue Shopping</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return ( 
      <div className="checkout-wrapper"> 
      <Container className="App">
        <h2 className='text-center'>Let's Checkout</h2>
          <Form className="form">
            <Col>
              <FormGroup>
                <Input
                  onChange= {this.inputChangeHandler}
                  type="first name"
                  name={"first name"}
                  value={this.state.firstName}
                  id="exampleEmail"
                  placeholder="first name"
                />
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <FormGroup>
                <Input
                  onChange= {this.inputChangeHandler}
                  type="last name"
                  name="last name"
                  value={this.state.lastName}
                  id="exampleEmail"
                  placeholder="last name"
                />
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <FormGroup>
                <Input
                  onChange= {this.inputChangeHandler}
                  type="address"
                  name="address"
                  value={this.state.adress}
                  id="exampleEmail"
                  placeholder="address"
                />
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <FormGroup>
                <Input
                  onChange= {this.inputChangeHandler}
                  type="city"
                  name="city"
                  value={this.state.city}
                  id="exampleEmail"
                  placeholder="city"
                />
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <FormGroup>
                <Input
                  onChange= {this.inputChangeHandler}
                  type="prefecture"
                  name="prefecture"
                  value={this.state.prefecture}
                  id="exampleEmail"
                  placeholder="prefecture"
                />
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <FormGroup>
                <Input
                  onChange= {this.inputChangeHandler}
                  type="zipcode"
                  name="zipcode"
                  value={this.state.zipCode}
                  id="exampleEmail"
                  placeholder="zipcode"
                />
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <FormGroup>
                <Input
                  onChange= {this.inputChangeHandler}
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  value={this.state.email}
                  id="exampleEmail"
                  placeholder="myemail@email.com"
                />
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>
            <Button className="save-address-button" disabled={this.state.submitDisabled}>Submit Address</Button>
            <div className="card-element">
            <CardElement style={cardElement}/>
            </div>
          </Form>
        <button className="checkout-button" disabled={false} onClick={this.submit}>Submit</button>
      </Container>
      </div> 
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    cartItems: state.shoppingCart.cartItems
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onClearCart: () => dispatch(clearCart())
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(injectStripe(CheckoutForm));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the bug is related to the misuse of the callback function of `this.setState`.

In your inputChangeHandler method, you passed three arguments to `this.setState()`, however, `this.setState()` expects you to pass only two arguments at most, with the second argument being the callback function.

Since you pass your callback function as the third argument, `this.setState()` will silently ignores it, so your validation method is not being called.

Another issue is related to the name parameter for the inputChangeHandler, the inputChangeHandler will only receive the event object, not the name. In order to access the name attribute of the input element, you will need to access it through `event.target.name`

To solve the issues, you can change the inputChangeHandler to

```
inputChangeHandler = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    console.log('inputChange', event.target.name, event.target.value)

    // notice the square bracket, this means we use the computed variable as 
    // the object key, instead of using the string 'name' as object key
    // also the name attribute in your Input element must match your state's key
    // use name='lastName' instead of name='last name' as your state's key is lastName
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    }, this.canSubmit) // changing this line
}
```

If you want to keep your `console.log(this.state.submitDisabled)`, you can add it inside your validation method.

```
canSubmit = () => {
    console.log("canSubmit", this.state.submitDisabled) // add it here
    const { firstName, lastName, address, city, prefecture, zipCode, email} = this.state
    if (validator.isAlpha(firstName) 
    && validator.isAlpha(lastName) 
    && address > 0
    && validator.isAlpha(city)
    && validator.isAlpha(prefecture)
    && zipCode > 0
    && validator.isEmail(email)) {
      this.setState({submitDisabled: false})
    } else {
      this.setState({submitDisabled: true})
    }
}
```

In the render method, I think you mean

`if (this.state.paymentComplete)`

instead of

`if (this.state.complete)`

Also, the button at the bottom, you hard-coded the disabled attribute value

```
<button
    className="checkout-button"
    disabled={false}
    onClick={this.submit}
>
    Submit
</button>
```

maybe you mean

```
<button
    className="checkout-button"
    disabled={this.state.submitDisabled}
    onClick={this.submit}
>
    Submit
</button>
```

As a side note, the type attribute for the input element should be 'text', 'number', 'checkbox', etc... Instead of some random text like 'last name' or 'prefecture'

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I tried this and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Is the canSubmit method being called and the state being updated now?

Comment: @frootloops I updated the answer, maybe you can check whether it's working now

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out. I still can't get the type to appear in the inputs. I can see every key stroke and letter in the console though.

Comment: @frootloops The problem should be related to the inputChangeHandler, I updated the answer again, please let me know if it's working now or is there still some unexpected behavior.

Comment: I finally found the problem. The main problem was that some of the Input names did not match the items in the state. and `[event.target.name]: event.target.value`. Thanks for your help @Ray Chan